# Proper way to cite Wikipedia according to the Chicago Manual of Style?

Tags: citation

In *The Chicago Manual of Style*, 16th ed., it actually lists two ways to cite Wikipedia content. The first, in section 14.245, is of the form:

- "Style Guide," *Wikipedia*, last modified July 18, 2008, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_guide.

The second, in section 14.248, is of the form:

- *Wikipedia*, s.v. "Stevie Nicks," last modified July 19, 2008, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stevie_Nicks.

It's not clear which form to use when. That aside, what if I want to refer to a particular section for an entry. For example, assuming I use the second form above, I could do:

- Wikipedia, *Origin of the Term*, s.v. "Trolley Pole," last modified Mar 22, 2014, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trolley_pole.

In order to put the name of the section in italics, I thought it best to un-italicize "Wikipedia." Thoughts?

Comment: There are many referencing styles and none are more "proper" than any others.

Comment: Considering that CMoS devotes two entire chapters to it on everything from citing books to Supreme Court cases, the evidence would suggest otherwise.

Comment: And the CMOS is just one of many, as the very same Style Guide page you linked to lists.

Comment: You would not normally list a section (heading) of an article in your bibliography; do not do it for Wikipedia. And definitely keep Wikipedia italicized. That's the convention for titles of major works and should not be changed arbitrarily.

Comment: If there's any commentary in CMOS near the bibliographic styling that you show in your article, please include it. It would help to know what's causing your confusion here. Also, if you only care about CMOS style you might want to reflect that in the question title (instead of saying "proper" which may bother some descriptivists, as you can see above).

Comment: Wikipedia itself [suggests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citing_Wikipedia#Examples) "Wikipedia contributors, 'Plagiarism,' *Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia*, http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Plagiarism&oldid=5139350 (accessed August 10, 2004)." That's CMoS. It also provides examples for other styles.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: Thanks! I never noticed their citation page before. If your response were an actual answer, I'd make it the official answer.

Comment: Presumably somebody has mandated that you adhere to the Chicago Manual of Style in the first place. So why not simply ask them which style they prefer where? (And if nobody has mandated that you use it, then which form do *you* prefer?)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a list about the English language, not about a particular style manual, which can be consulted directly by those whom it interests.

Comment: @David The question is nearly 8 years old. I've long since gotten whatever answer(s) I was ever going to get. If you've got nothing better to do than vote on an 8-year-old question, knock yourself out.

Answer (score 3):

With regards to your first question of, it's not clear which to use when, I think it might be a matter of how you think about Wikipedia, and how you're using it in your paper:

- if you think of it as an online encyclopedia, then you go with 14.248 (because the heading there is Dictionaries and encyclopedias online", and other examples in the list include the Encyclopaedia Britannica Online and the MW Online)
- if you think of it as just a website with content you're using, then go with 14.245 (aka "Citations of web content").

As for your second question, I would go with:

> *Wikipedia*, s.v. "Trolley Pole: Origin of the Term," last modified Mar 22, 2014, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trolley_pole.

...but you definitely need to keep the italics in the same place as in the example they provided!

Answer (score 2):

<sub>If you are asking "How do people generally cite Wikipedia according to the Chicago Manual of Style",</sub>

The *usual* way is to simply use the Wikipedia tool. In the left navigation bar of every Wikipedia page, under `Tools` section, you can find a "Cite *this* page" link. Clicking that link will bring you to a page with pre-generated citations formats. The [Chicago style looks like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:CiteThisPage&page=Style_guide&id=679089515#Chicago_style):

> Wikipedia contributors, "Style guide," *Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia,* https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Style_guide&oldid=679089515 (accessed September 22, 2015).

> Wikipedia contributors, "Stevie Nicks," *Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia,* https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Stevie_Nicks&oldid=679854093 (accessed September 22, 2015).

The characters "`Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia,`" are italicized.

That said, if you have a reviewer (the *person* who mandates you to use so-called "Chicago Style")  then you'd probably need to cite it whatever way they prescribe.